# Create custom keys in array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a for each loop set up to insert values in to a custom array I created. For some reason when I run a for loop on the array afterwards using one of the custom keys I set, I get no results.

**My array in the for each loop**

```
$posting_ids[] .= "[posting_id] => ".$value['posting_id'].", [posting_likes] => ".$value['total_likes']."";
```

**Echoing the array in for loop**

```
for($a=0; $a < count($posting_ids); $a++) {
    echo $posting_ids['posting_id'];
}
```

**I would like to be able to pull all the posting_ids and posting_likes like the example below**

```
Array (
  [0] => 
       [posting_id] => 1 
       [posting_likes] => 15 
  [1] => 
       [posting_id] => 2 
       [posting_likes] => 19 
)
```

The results populating this array are being pulled from a foreach loop, so it needs to be able to store multiple values in the array.

Comment: I have no idea what you think you're doing there, but you're not setting any array keys. Use `var_dump($posting_ids)` to see what your array actually looks like. Keys are set using `$array[$key] = $value`, not by concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/phf-ydt), it may help you.

```
<?php
  $posting_ids[0]['posting_id' ] = 1;
  $posting_ids[0]['total_likes'] = 10;

  $posting_ids[1]['posting_id' ] = 2;
  $posting_ids[1]['total_likes'] = 20;

  for($a=0; $a < count($posting_ids); $a++){
    echo $posting_ids[$a]['posting_id'];
  }
```

Comment: Please avoid just posting links as answers - if it breaks your efforts become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
$posting_ids[] .= "[posting_id] => ".$value['posting_id'].", [posting_likes] => ".$value['total_likes']."";
```

do like this-

```
$posting_ids['posting_id'] = $value['posting_id'];
$posting_ids['posting_likes'] = $value['total_likes'];
```

**EDIT:As per your updated posted you can do like**

```
while() { //your loop
$posting_ids = array('posting_id' => $value['posting_id'],      'posting_likes'=>$value['total_likes']);
}
```

so that you print $posting_ids it will print like

```
Array (
  [0] => 
       [posting_id] => 1 
       [posting_likes] => 15 
  [1] => 
       [posting_id] => 2 
       [posting_likes] => 19 
)
```

Comment: Running that through a `PRINT_R` I'm getting all the posting IDs in one key, where as I need some type of identifier for each key.
Array ( [posting_id] => 161514131211108 [posting_bumps] => 10001000 )
`Needs to be`
Array ([0] => [posting_id] => 16 [posting_likes] => 2 
[1] => [posting_id] => 17 [posting_likes] => 1 )

Comment: @ChristianRankin did not get you what exactly you want.